# I can't use 2 piece onCreateContextMenu

Tags: java, android

I can't create 2 onCreateContextMenu. *I am taking this error*: **"Error:(101, 17) error: method onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu,View,ContextMenuInfo) is already defined in class MainActivity"** - **This is my MainActivity.java** *and* **How can i use 2 onCreateContextMenu?**

**Thanks for helping**

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button2); {
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.color_context_menu,menu);
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.button);{
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.color_context_menu,menu);
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You can't define 2 methods with the same signature in one class.  Otherwise JVM won't know which method to use

Comment: How can i use this signature for my button2 and button? Because i only can use one signature.Can you help?

Comment: Just use `if-else if` in one method

Comment: I only used this signature one time and I only use this code for my all buttons registerForContextMenu (button2);  and I can open my context menu(popup). Thanks for your help.